# How to set the syntax in pwndbg's context to AT&T?

Tags: gdb, disassembly

By default it seems to use intel syntax

I tried with `set disassembly-flavor at`, but this only seems to affect the disassembly produced by the `disassemble` command, and not the one shown in the context window of pwndbg.

I apologize if this is not SO's worthy, but I really have tried looking online and nothing seems to show up.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I did a reverse engineer. I found the problem and the solution. Basically, the syntax flavor is hard-coded. I'm working in a pull request in the pwndbg project with my solution. [Github:  pwndbg/pwndbg ---> Pull request #863](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg/pull/860).

If you want to change it, you need root permissions and change a file in the `/usr/share/pwndbg/` directory. Add the follow line `cs.syntax = 2` in the `disasm` module.

```
Main path:      /usr/share/pwndbg/
Relative path:  ./pwndbg/disasm/__init__.py
File Path:      /usr/share/pwndbg/pwndbg/disasm/__init__.py
```

```py
@pwndbg.memoize.reset_on_objfile
def get_disassembler_cached(arch, ptrsize, endian, extra=None):
    // Code...
    cs = Cs(arch, mode)
    cs.syntax = 2    // Add this line
    cs.detail = True
    return cs
```

The package `capstone` has these definitions:

```py
# Capstone syntax value
CS_OPT_SYNTAX_DEFAULT =   0  # Default assembly syntax of all platforms (CS_OPT_SYNTAX)
CS_OPT_SYNTAX_INTEL =     1  # Intel X86 asm syntax - default syntax on X86 (CS_OPT_SYNTAX, CS_ARCH_X86)
CS_OPT_SYNTAX_ATT =       2  # ATT asm syntax (CS_OPT_SYNTAX, CS_ARCH_X86)
CS_OPT_SYNTAX_NOREGNAME = 3  # Asm syntax prints register name with only number - (CS_OPT_SYNTAX, CS_ARCH_PPC, CS_ARCH_ARM)
CS_OPT_SYNTAX_MASM =      4  # MASM syntax (CS_OPT_SYNTAX, CS_ARCH_X86)
```

Answer (score 1):

add  "**set disassembly-flavor att**" to  ~/.gdbinit

Comment: it works now in the latest pwngdb github code.